# Naturally removing blackheads at home

Tags: personal-care

I have bad blackheads around my nose. I don't want to get chemical treatments.

Is there any way to get rid of them naturally at home?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just saying, after many years of 'natural', I found Nitrogena's Black Men's face wash did the trick. Did in days what I hadn't got in years.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a blackhead remover tool like this https://www.thebodyshop.com/en-gb/face/accessories/blackhead-remover/p/p000947 if you don't want to squeeze with your fingernails.

Wash your face thoroughly and then steam it over a bowl of very hot or boiling water for a couple of minutes or so. Dry your face, use a mirror to see what you're  doing, and use the removal tool or your (cleaned and scrubbed) fingers to apply pressure to each one, preferably without damaging the surrounding skin. If you live somewhere hot and humid, you won't need  to steam your face - the object of that is simply to soften the skin and open up the pores, which happens anyway in humid, hot climates.

Afterwards, wash the area with soap, use cold water to rinse it off, pat dry and apply a light moisturizer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use certain home made remedies for this as described below:

- Grind tender leaves of guava, mango and pomegranate to a fine paste and apply over affected part regularly.
- Grind Red ixora flowers and petals of rose, add some turmeric to the paste and apply regularly.
- Burn out lemon's outer skin, grind and mix it with buttermilk, apply regularly.
- Neem leaf paste along with turmeric is also another good option.

After applying any one of the above pastes, perform a clean wash to the surface.Repeat the steps for 10-20 days until you find changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use tea tree oil or witch hazel

[Dr Axe - see 11. Essential Oil Spot Treatment](https://draxe.com/how-to-get-rid-of-blackheads/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Lemon and Olive Oil, this will help you removing the blackspots.

1. Mix lemon juice olive oil equally.
2. Apply this solution to your face and on those areas where you spot blackheads.
3. Use soft tissue or cotton to apply this mixture on your face. ...
4. Leave it for a few hours.
5. Wash it off with water and dry it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a paste of 1 tablespoon honey and 1 tablespoon of milk. Mix it thoroughly then dip some cotton in it and apply that cotton to the affected area. Leave it to dry. After drying  peel of the cotton swiftly and you're ready to go blackhead free.

Comment: Hi Chaudhry, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE. We hope you enjoy your time here. Please visit the Help Centre (? menu icon) above for information about how better to use this site.